# ¿Cómo puedo usar como condición un valor almacenado en una variable colección de Genexus?

Tags: mysql, condiciones, genexus, tomcat, colecciones

Estoy aprendiendo a usar Genexus y se me presenta el siguiente inconveniente:
Estoy leyendo un archivo plano con registros para ser insertados en la DB, y necesito filtrar algunos datos que si no se encuentran en la DB, estos no se inserten.
Debo llenar con valores obtenidos de un For Each una variable colección, para ello uso el siguiente código:

```
For Each
       Where EntId = &EntId //&EntId viene por parámetro

       &SdtProd.ProdCod = &ProdCod

       &colProducto.add(&SdtProd)
   EndFor
```

Ahora con los valores de *ProdCod* que se guardaron en la colección, debo hacer la condición de que si el valor leído en el registro no se encuentra en la colección (por lo tanto, tampoco en la DB) este registro no se guarde. Para ello estaba intentando usar:

```
For &SdtProd in &colProducto
        If &colProducto.ProdCod = &RegistroProdCod

//Código para insertar en la DB

EndIf
EndFor
```

Pero con ese código me arroja un error de que está mal la sentencia. Agradecería sus opiniones y ayuda!

[image: código de For each]

[image: código de condición]

Comment: Pulsá en [edit] y mostrá el error _específico_ que estás teniendo.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando recorres el archivo plano deberías recorrer el SDT para revisar si ese registro está o no, en caso de que esté lo das de alta, caso contrario no:

```
Do while dfrnext() = 0

   &ExisteRegistroEnSDT(variable boolean) = false

   &i = dfrgtxt(&Linetxt)
   
   For &SdtProd in &colProducto

     If &SdtProd.ProdCod = &Linetxt.Trim()
        &ExisteRegistroEnSDT = true
        Exit
     EndIf
         
   EndFor

   If &ExisteRegistroEnSDT
      //Código para dar de alta el registro
   EndIf 

   &i = dfrclose()
EndDo
```

Comment: Buen día! Una consulta, ese For Each no hará un recorrido por cada registro a insertar?

Comment: Entiendo que los registros a insertar estarían en el SDT &colProducto. Lo que hace ese for each es comparar los registros existentes con los registros a insertar que están dentro de la colección &colProducto. Quizás deberías detallar un poco mas cuál es el problema.

Comment: Nono, los registros a insertar en un txt que los lee con un dfrg, y los guarda en una variable, y de esa variable se substrae los campos.

Comment: En lo que me trabe es como recorrer el sdt que ya haya guardados todos los identificadores de productos en una sola vuelta, y que con esos identificadores guardados, se comparen con el registro leído y si se el dato del registro leído es igual a un producto guardado en el sdt, que ejecute la lógica de la carga

Comment: ¿Qué sería "el registro leído"? ¿Un registro en una tabla, (es lo que comprendí, por eso el for each) o en dónde?

Comment: Registro leído sería el registro que agarra del archivo plano (txt) que importo mediante un fileupload, por eso el drfg que uso

Comment: ¿Y qué información tiene cada registro que estás leyendo con DFRGTxt()? ¿El código de producto a insertar(ProdCod)?

Comment: el txt trae los datos de la operacion del cliente en una entidad, en un WebPanel selecciono la entidad del txt, ent (de entidad) puede tener muchos prodcod, entonces lo que debo hacer es buscar por entidad, y q' haya prodcod asociados a esa entidad, si no lo hay, no se insertaran registros. lo que debo evitar es hacer una consulta a la DB por cada registro leido. por lo tanto lo que quisiera hacer es guardar en una variable coleccion todos los prodcod que hayan asociados a una ent y usarlo como condicion a la coleccion (q' si prodcod en el registro coincide con un dato en coleccion que guarde)

Comment: Edité la respuesta para que se pueda comparar lo que se está leyendo desde el TXT contra lo que tiene el SDT y en base a eso dar de alta o no.